# Rendering of list item marker when in column

Tags: html, browser, multiple-columns, listitem

Chrome does not number list items when the list is displaied in several columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing li number in column</title>
</head>
<body>
<ol style="column-count:3">
<li>This is item 1.</li>
<li>This is item 2.</li>
<li>This is item 3.</li>
<li>This is item 4.</li>
<li>This is item 5.</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is interpreted without numbering list items except in the first column.

Is there another way to do to get the expected rendering (all items numbered) ?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordered list number with css multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992924/ordered-list-number-with-css-multiple-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a bit of CSS to make the default style position inside. Try:

```
li {
  list-style: inside decimal;
}
```

Comment: Also work with icons :<li style="list-style: inside url(bullet.png);">This is item 1.</li>